# Using Azure Data Factory utilities to generate ARM Template does not generate the location tag for the Data Factory resource

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-yaml

When using the "publish" on the Azure Data Factory the ARM Template is generated

```
        "name": "[parameters('factoryName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "location": "[parameters('dataFactory_location')]"
```

When I use the NPM task in my build pipeline (@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities) it generates the following:

```
        "name": "[parameters('factoryName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "properties": {}
```

Running the process on my local machine has the same results (invalid ARM template)

So currently creating the ARM template via the CI/CD pipeline does not create a valid ARM template.

I have followed these instructions to get it going in my pipeline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements

Any suggestions or pointers would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the issue but would suggest not including the factory in the ARM template as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters#cicd

Including the factory will cause other downstream issues when using the automated publish flow for CI/CD such as removing the git configuration on the source factory, so deploying global parameters with PowerShell is the recommended approach. By not including the factory in the ARM template, this error will not occur. Feel free to continue the discussion here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/285